# Sabre - hotel availability API - Error

Tags: sabre

I'm getting the following error message

```
<faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidSecurityToken</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid or Expired binary security token: null</faultstring><detail><StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.session.USG_INVALID_SECURITY_TOKEN</StackTrace></detail></soap-env:Fault></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

The following is my request to the hotels availability API.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">client</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>'.$pcc.'</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>YourConversationId</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"></eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>
        </eb:MessageHeader> 
        <Security xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <BinarySecurityToken>'.$sabreKey.'</BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <eb:OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns:eb="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" TimeStamp="2011-01-26T12:30:00-06:00" Version="1.10.1">
            <eb:POS>
                <eb:Source PseudoCityCode="'.$pcc.'" /></eb:POS>
            <eb:AvailRequestSegments>
                <eb:AvailRequestSegment>
                    <eb:StayDateRange Start="12-10" End="12-15" />
                    <eb:RoomStayCandidates>
                        <eb:RoomStayCandidate>
                            <eb:GuestCounts>
                                <eb:GuestCount Count="1" /></eb:GuestCounts>
                        </eb:RoomStayCandidate>
                    </eb:RoomStayCandidates>
                    <eb:HotelSearchCriteria xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="eb:HotelSearchCriteria_type0">
                        <eb:Criterion>
                            <eb:HotelRef HotelCityCode="DFW" /></eb:Criterion>
                    </eb:HotelSearchCriteria>
                </eb:AvailRequestSegment>
            </eb:AvailRequestSegments>
        </eb:OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here's What I did before making the request to the hotel availability API. I received my wsse:BinarySecurityToken from SessionCreateRQ stored the variable containing the token into.

```
  <BinarySecurityToken>'.$sabreKey.'</BinarySecurityToken>
```

Why am I getting this error message my credentials are correct. BTW I have production credentials.

Thanks I'm looking forward to some help

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that the security token is correct, you might be working on an incorrect environment. 
For instance, if you created a session on PROD but sent the subsequent request to CERT, this error would be returned.

Make sure both requests are being sent to the same endpoint. If the problem persists, please contact the helpdesk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Bruno. Both request where being sent to the same endpoint. I figured out what the problem is, that was not it. I will post the solution in a couple minutes as I'm sure my solution will help many people that face the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here's what the issue was the Sabre documentation to said to include the following tags in the request.

```
<eb:Security xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
        <eb:BinarySecurityToken>'.$sabreKey.'</eb:BinarySecurityToken>
    </eb:Security>
```

But that was leading to an error.

So I Then tried removing the eb namespace and my tags where the following.

```
<Security xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
        <BinarySecurityToken>'.$sabreKey.'</BinarySecurityToken>
    </Security>
```

If you look at the xml request in my results. You will understand this did not work. I then tried changing the tags again and got it to work.

The tags I'm using now where not in the documentation I was reading.That's what had me confused. By using the following tags is how I got my request to work.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String"     EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">'.$sabreKey.'</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

I'm sure this will help many people out as the documentation was flawed when it came down to this particular tag.